# PHP 5.5 won't recognise server when using symfony

Tags: symfony, php-5.5

Im using php 5.5.27 in mac and when I run `$php app/console server:run` I got:

```
  [InvalidArgumentException]                                
  There are no commands defined in the "server" namespace.
```

I also review php version by `php -v`, with `php app/check.php` and it shows the same version php 5.5.27, any insights?

I install symfony with symfony-installer, and php was already installed in my machine.

Even when I run `$php app/console` I got:

```
Symfony version 2.0.12 - app/dev/debug

Usage:
  [options] command [arguments]

Options:
  --help           -h Display this help message.
  --quiet          -q Do not output any message.
  --verbose        -v Increase verbosity of messages.
  --version        -V Display this application version.
  --ansi              Force ANSI output.
  --no-ansi           Disable ANSI output.
  --no-interaction -n Do not ask any interactive question.
  --shell          -s Launch the shell.
  --env            -e The Environment name.
  --no-debug          Switches off debug mode.

Available commands:
  help                                  Displays help for a command
  list                                  Lists commands
assetic
  assetic:dump                          Dumps all assets to the filesystem
assets
  assets:install                        Installs bundles web assets under a public web directory
cache
  cache:clear                           Clears the cache
  cache:warmup                          Warms up an empty cache
container
  container:debug                       Displays current services for an application
doctrine
  doctrine:cache:clear-metadata         Clears all metadata cache for a entity manager
  doctrine:cache:clear-query            Clears all query cache for a entity manager
  doctrine:cache:clear-result           Clears result cache for a entity manager
  doctrine:database:create              Creates the configured databases
  doctrine:database:drop                Drops the configured databases
  doctrine:ensure-production-settings   Verify that Doctrine is properly configured for a production environment.
  doctrine:generate:crud                Generates a CRUD based on a Doctrine entity
  doctrine:generate:entities            Generates entity classes and method stubs from your mapping information
  doctrine:generate:entity              Generates a new Doctrine entity inside a bundle
  doctrine:generate:form                Generates a form type class based on a Doctrine entity
  doctrine:mapping:convert              Convert mapping information between supported formats.
  doctrine:mapping:import               Imports mapping information from an existing database
  doctrine:mapping:info                 Shows basic information about all mapped entities
  doctrine:query:dql                    Executes arbitrary DQL directly from the command line.
  doctrine:query:sql                    Executes arbitrary SQL directly from the command line.
  doctrine:schema:create                Executes (or dumps) the SQL needed to generate the database schema
  doctrine:schema:drop                  Executes (or dumps) the SQL needed to drop the current database schema
  doctrine:schema:update                Executes (or dumps) the SQL needed to update the database schema to match the current mapping metadata
generate
  generate:bundle                       Generates a bundle
  generate:doctrine:crud                Generates a CRUD based on a Doctrine entity
  generate:doctrine:entities            Generates entity classes and method stubs from your mapping information
  generate:doctrine:entity              Generates a new Doctrine entity inside a bundle
  generate:doctrine:form                Generates a form type class based on a Doctrine entity
init
  init:acl                              Mounts ACL tables in the database
mopa
  mopa:generate:crud                    Generates a CRUD based on a Doctrine entity
router
  router:debug                          Displays current routes for an application
  router:dump-apache                    Dumps all routes as Apache rewrite rules
swiftmailer
  swiftmailer:spool:send                Sends emails from the spool
```

It won't show server command :(

Comment: How did you install it? What happens when you run `php app/console`?

Comment: @TomášVotruba I install symfony with symfony-installer, and php was already installed in my machine. Due to length, I add the output in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You run Symfony Version 2.0 its too old. Upgrade to the latest version or the LTS version first then you have the server command. Otherweise you can't use them.

The command `server:run` is for version 2.3 after on higher versions its `server:start`

here is the manual

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/web_server/built_in.html

Comment: Thanks. I have inherit a project, downloaded it from server and I´m trying to fix little bugs. Will I have troubles if I update symfony 2.7? I´m kind of new at this

Comment: If you have really version 2.0 then you can't very easy update to 2.7. You can try it and fix your problems. That would be a better way.

Comment: Good luck for the upgrade !